# Docker compose up fails with error invalid type

Tags: docker, docker-compose, health-check

I have a .Net core API that needs to run database migrations to a MySql container on startup but it is failing with syntax error as below :

```
The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.mysqldata.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
services.registrationapi.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

I have tried all types of fixes but still facing same error. My docker-compose is as below :

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  registrationapi:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "5060:5000"
    depends_on:
      mysqldata:
        condition: service_healthy
          

  mysqldata:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    ports:
      - "33306:3306"
    environment:
       MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
       MYSQL_DATABASE: RegistrationDB
       MYSQL_USER: dbuser
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypsswrd
    volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["/usr/bin/mysql --user=dbuser --password=mypsswrd --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""]
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 15
          
volumes:
    dbdata:
```

I have tried to amend the file as per this [post](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/control-startup-and-shutdown-order-of-containers-in-docker-compose-ff7320f868e2) but it still fails with same error.

I have tried removing [] from test but syntax validation still fails.

What is the exact syntax for this?

**UPDATE**
I am getting error as below :
[image: dockercompose]

after updating the yaml file as appropriate:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  registrationapi:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "5060:5000"
    depends_on:
      mysqldata:
        condition: service_healthy
          

  mysqldata:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    ports:
      - "33306:3306"
    environment:
       MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
       MYSQL_DATABASE: RegistrationDB
       MYSQL_USER: dbuser
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypsswrd
    volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/mysql", "--user=dbuser", "--password=mypsswrd", "--execute", "SHOW DATABASES;"]
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 15
          
volumes:
    dbdata:
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the errors you've reported. Your healthcheck is generating an error (which you haven't reported) because you're not following the correct syntax. See [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) to details (also the example [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck)).

Comment: @larsks check update to the question still appears as if yaml has syntax issues, Same error even when I  set ports as for example ["5009:5000"]

Comment: Your updated `docker-compose.yaml` works for me with no errors.

Comment: @larsks If I may ask what environment are you running on ? I am on Debian 10 buster

Comment: It looks as if the version of `docker-compose` available on Debian 10 is quite old. The current version is `2.2.3`, but with Docker on Debian 10, `apt-get install docker-compose` gets me version `1.21.0`. You can download a recent release of `docker-compose` [from the releases page](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases).

Comment: @larsks i have upgraded to 2.2.3 . now left with error  "services.mysqldata.ports must be a list "

Answer (score 1):

One of the most efficient ways to check the configuration of your docker-compose.yml file is by running **config**. This points to the possible issues in your docker-compose file and can be run as shown below:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-file.yml config
```

The issue in your file is the **healthcheck** section as indicated when I ran the above command for your file.

```
ERROR: Service "mysqldata" defines an invalid healthcheck: when "test" is a list the first item must be either NONE, CMD or CMD-SHELL
```

Taking reference from the [official documtation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck), the fix that worked for me was to represent the `test` value as blocks of double-quotes prepended with `CMD`.

> test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/mysql", "--user=dbuser",
> "--password=mypsswrd", "--execute", "SHOW DATABASES;"]

Comment: I have amended check update, seems the yaml still has syntax issues